# how do i convert these c# winform codes to be compatible on c# wpf?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, winforms, converters, invoke

hi im working on a project that uses invoke and threads.. it is a simple remote desktop program with chat.. i got a sample here on the internet in c# winform, but i would like to convert it to wpf.. i have no problem in sending message to another client using the wpf program but it cannot receive ( or cannot read) the sent messages from the others..   i think it has something to do with the thread and the invoke method, i read that wpf does invoke differently and i did try the dispatcher.invoke, but it still doesnt do the trick

pls hellp

here's the code

```
wait = new Thread(new ThreadStart(waitForData));
wait.Start();
```

that snippet above is executed when a successful connection is made in tcpclient

```
    private void waitForData()
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream read = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            while (read.CanRead)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

                read.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                s = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(buffer);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Recieved data:" + new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(buffer));
                rcvMsg = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(buffer) + "\n";
                hasNewData = true;


                bool f = false;
                f = rcvMsg.Contains("##");
                bool comand = false;
                comand = rcvMsg.Contains("*+*-");

                   /*File receive*/

                 if (f)
                {
                    string d = "##";
                    rcvMsg = rcvMsg.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());
                    int lastLt = rcvMsg.LastIndexOf("|");
                    rcvMsg = rcvMsg.Substring(0, lastLt);
                    NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                    if (ns.CanWrite)
                    {
                        string dataS = "^^Y";
                        byte[] bf = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(dataS);
                        ns.Write(bf, 0, bf.Length);
                        ns.Flush();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        new Recieve_File().recieve_file(rcvMsg);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ec)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(ec.Message);
                    }

                }
                     /*Command-shutdown/restart/logoff*/
                else if (comand)
                {
                    string com = "*+*-";
                    rcvMsg = rcvMsg.TrimStart(com.ToCharArray());
                    execute_command(rcvMsg);

                }
                else
                {
                    this.Invoke(new setOutput(setOut));
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            wait.Abort();
            output.Text += "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace; 
        }

    }
```

the snippet above is a code that listens if there is a message or command.. the line
this.invoke(new setoutput(setout)) is a code for appending text in the rtb

hope someone could help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've posted a *lot* of code, but I'm assuming it's only the call to `Control.Invoke` which is causing the problem. In WPF, use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604732.aspx) (or [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)) instead, via the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property on the relevant UI element.

I'd also strongly encourage you to:

- Refactor your code into smaller methods
- Stop catching just `Exception` except at the top level of any large operation (it should just be a fall-back; usually you catch *specific* exceptions)
- Start following .NET naming conventions
- Add a `using` directive for `System` so you can just write `Console.WriteLine` instead of `System.Console.WriteLine` everywhere
- Use `Encoding.ASCII` instead of creating a new `ASCIIEncoding` each time you need one
- Use a `StreamReader` to read character data from a stream, instead of reading it as binary data first and then encoding it
- For either `Stream` or `TextReader`, don't ignore the return value from `Read` - it tells you how many bytes or characters have been read